# Trying to prove a set equality

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Suppose $f:X \to Y $ is a map and let $A \subseteq X $ And $T \subseteq Y $. I want to show that $f^{-1} ( f(A)) \supseteq A $. Also, I want to show that $T = f( f^{-1} (T)) \iff T \subseteq Im f $.

My try

for first one if $x \notin f^{-1} ( f(A)) $ then surely by definition $f(x) \notin f(A) $ and so $x \notin A $

For second part,  Suppose $T \subseteq Im f $. if $y \in f(f^{-1}(T)) $ then there is some $x \in f^{-1}(T) $ with $f(x) = y $. But since $x \in f^{-1}(T) $ then $f(x) \in T $ by definition and so $f( f^{-1} (T)) \subseteq T $. To show the other inclusion suppose $y \notin f ( f^{-1}(T))  $ so there is NO $t \in f^{-1}(T) $ with $y = f(t) $. In other words, there is NOT such $f(t)$ in $T$. Hence, $y \notin T$. We have shown that $T \subseteq f(f^{-1}(T)) $. Conversely, we suppose $T = f(f^{-1}(T)) $. If $y \notin Im f $, then there does not exist $x \in X $ such that $f(x) = y \in Y $. Im stuck here. I cannot see how from here we get that $T \subset Im f $

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Is my proof correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have written down looks correct to me, although here is an easier argument for $T\subseteq f(f^{-1}(T))$. Suppose $T\subseteq Im(f)$ and $t\in T$. Then there exists $x\in X$ with $f(x) = t$. Thus $x\in f^{-1}(T)$ and $t\in f(f^{-1}(T))$. Since this is true of all $t\in T$, we have $T\subseteq f(f^{-1}(T))$.

For the last stage, suppose $T = f(f^{-1}(T))$ and $t\in T$. Then from the equality, there is $x\in f^{-1}(T)$ such that $f(x) = t$. Hence $t\in Im(f)$, and so $T\subseteq Im(f)$.

Answer (score 0):

$f(f^{-1}(T))\subseteq f(X)=\text{im}f$.

Combine this with $T= f(f^{-1}(T))$ to arrive at $T\subseteq\text{im}f$.